# Power Query Help - HTML Tables

Tags: powerquery

Can anyone help me get this table into excel via Power Query. No matter how I try to follow the path on "inspect" I can't seem to get to the table.

https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/rookies.php

let
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/rookies.php")),
Data = Source{1}[Data],
Children = Data{0}[Children],
Children1 = Children{1}[Children],
Children2 = Children1{5}[Children],
Children3 = Children2{4}[Children],
Children4 = Children3{0}[Children],
Children5 = Children4{0}[Children],
Children6 = Children5{2}[Children],
Children7 = Children6{0}[Children]
in
Children7

Comment: The table is built by javascript that runs in the browser. It does not run when Power Query opens the URL, hence the table is never rendered and not accessible to Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

## Web.BrowserContents

> The table is built by javascript that runs in the browser. It does not run when Power Query opens the URL, hence the table is never rendered and not accessible to Power Query

The function [Web.BrowserContents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-browsercontents) is designed to handle that. For example:

```
Web.BrowserContents("https://microsoft.com", [
    WaitFor = [
        Selector = "div.ready",
        Timeout = #duration(0,0,0,10) ]
])
```

## Finding Selectors

Think of `RowSelector` as selecting a table row
Then for every row, you select "columns" using the `columnSelectors`. When Power Query loops, those selectors are combined giving you a single `cell` of the tabular-like data in a webpage. You can use anything, like a list of `div`s.

Power BI has a option to auto-detect tables. You can be more precise if you use CSS Selectors.

## Testing Selectors in a browser

[image]

In your browser console (like firefox) type `$$("tr.player-row")`. Then Hover over the crosshairs to see which columns that selector will match.

## Solution

[image]

```
let
    UseLocalCache = true,
    Source_Web = "https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/rookies.php",
    Source_Local = "file:///C:/temp/rookies.html",
    Response =
        if not UseLocalCache
        then Web.BrowserContents( Source_Web )
        else File.Contents( Source_Local ),

    columnSelectors = {
        { "Player", "tr.player-row :nth-child(3)" },
        { "Rank", "tr.player-row :nth-child(1)" },
        { "Worst", "tr.player-row :nth-child(6)" },
        { "Avg", "tr.player-row :nth-child(7)" },
        { "Std. Dev.", "tr.player-row :nth-child(8)" }
    },
    // sometimes you need to also declare the function if it didn't automatically coerce right
    // { "Rank", "tr.player-row :nth-child(1)", each _ },
    rowSelector = 
        [RowSelector = "tr.player-row"],   

    table_stats = Html.Table( Response, columnSelectors, rowSelector ),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        table_stats,
        {{"Rank", Int64.Type}, {"Worst", Int64.Type},
         {"Avg", type number}, {"Std. Dev.", type number}}
    ),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",
        {{"Rank", Order.Ascending}} )
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

It's quicker to test your query if you save the file offline. You can toggle that with `UseLocalCache`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't think Web.BrowserContents works in my version of PQ: Expression.Error: The name 'Web.BrowserContents' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: Do you have access to Powershell, Python, or anything? Sometimes it's just easier to have them do the work, then export to a `csv` to import. -- For python check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)